# Web browsers send multiple request to custom Java server

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpoolexecutor

I have had to make a custom java thread pooled server as part of a bigger project .

I have run into an issue which is hurting the neurons inside my head since atleast one complete day and night .

What I have done is simple (followed an online resource ). I have a while loop , that loops forever . Comes a request , it accepts it and sends it to the thread pool (Java executor framework).

```
protected ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);

while(! isStopped()){
    Socket clientSocket = null;
    try {
        clientSocket = this.serverSocket.accept();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        if(isStopped()) {
            System.out.println("Server Stopped.") ;
            return;
        }
        throw new RuntimeException("Error accepting client connection", e);
    }
    this.threadPool.execute(
        new Task(clientSocket,
        "Test")
    );
    //System.out.println("Processed");
}
this.threadPool.shutdown();
```

Can't get any simpler right ?

also the Task class ,just accepts a socket , and writes to it's output stream

```
public class Task implements Runnable{

    protected Socket clientSocket = null;
    protected String serverText   = null;

    public Task(Socket clientSocket, String serverText) {
        this.clientSocket = clientSocket;
        this.serverText   = serverText;
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            InputStream input  = clientSocket.getInputStream();
            OutputStream output = clientSocket.getOutputStream();
            long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
            output.write(("HTTP/1.1 200 OK\n\nWorkerRunnable: " +
                    this.serverText + " - " +
                    time +
                    "").getBytes());
            output.close();
            input.close();
            System.out.println("Request processed: " + time);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            //report exception somewhere.
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**Here is the issue .** 
**Chrome**
Whenever I write localhost:9004 in Chrome , I see (Request Processed : time) on the console , multiple times , even though I just hit the URL once  .

How is this even possible ? . What is happening is multiple requests to the server are initiated for some reason OR the Java Executor framework is at fault here perhaps executing one request multiple times or so ? . I dont believe either of the reasons can be true

**Firefox**

When I hit the url from FF , Request Processed  correctly comes once on the console each time I hit the server. (rarely it does behave like chrome , like on some random moments , it shows two Request Processed messages for a single URL hit)

**Custom Java Client**
When I hit the URL from a custom made java client application , The server application's console window correctly shows one Request Processed tag for each request .

I even hit the URL 10 times , blazingly fast inside a for loop , and I correctly received 10 Request Processed messages on the server end

**IE**
same as chrome .

Can you guys please provide me some insight on the situation ? . I apologize for the length of the question .

Thank you .

Comment: Here analysing browser behaviour is important. Since browsers work on TCP/IP, it is needed to know if browsers wait for some kind of acknowledgement. I am not talk about HTTP request/response, I am refering to mechanism that is happening on IP or Transport layer.

Comment: I guess the reason is the browser is starting several connections in parallel (maybe testing for different protocols or precaching typical resources or stuff like that).
Have you tried to sniff the incoming traffic (e.g. maybe use a tool like wireshark to check what is going on between the browser and your app)?

Comment: @Matthias . No but I think it is going to give insights . I am currently downloading the utility . Thanks

Comment: @LearnMore . So do you suggest this is normal , and I carry on forward with the application ?

Comment: No, I am suggesting that you need to consider behavior of clients which are sending requests to your server. And based on that, you have to decide how to code your server. Here you can not change browser behavior so you have to analyze.

Comment: @Matthias. I used wireshark ,and got a few answers . So I would like to specially thank you for pushing me one step closer . 

Wireshark shows exactly that number of transactions between the source and destination , as are in the console window of my custom server .

Comment: Well, I am happy to hear this. So at least your server seems to work right. If the multiple request do not bother your server, you can probably accept this. If you only want one "valid" request, you somehow have to filter the extra requests Chrome and IE do.
Which url are you trying exactly to connect from the browser to your server? with http:// or without?

Comment: @Matthias. I was analyzing the wireshark's findings , and found out that the TCP communication between the client and server is gone beserk. 

Like for instance , the client sends a SYN to the server ,the server says SYN, ACK . Now the client should say ACK . Rather the client again sends the SYN etc etc . Do you have any idea as to why would all these discrepancies be happening ?

Comment: @Matthias to connect to the browser , i am using a URL without http . Does it matter ?

Comment: I am not really experienced with differences between browsers and all that. But I guess that if you do not specify a protocol, the browser may default to http, but also might to try different protocols in parallel threads.
Maybe try url http://127.0.0.1:9004/ in Chrome and check if the behaviour changes

Answer (score 0):

There are several requests sent out by the browser for different purposes. For once the ordinary HTTP request as you know it, then there is a if-modified request, that should only grab the header, and finally there is a request for the web-site icon.

Printing out the actual request sent by the browser might enlighten you. ;)